# plot a simple linear regression model

Tags: r, math, statistics

How to plot a simple linear regression model, weight = a*diameter + b in R(tool)
where weight and diameter are already provided in a dataset.Previously I have plotted a model to show relation between diameter and weight.[image]

Comment: `abline(lm(weight ~ diameter))`  but it seems obvious that this is _not_ a linear relationship.

Comment: There is a relationship between the whole weight and diameter . I tried  plotting these two attributes to see the shape(As can be seen in image). Based on this,
I was trying to fit the following models to the data:
A simple linear model, weight = a* diameter + b
Currently I have the equation of linear regression as :                      
                                                                                                           
    Weight =  -1.0364513 + 4.5729532*Diameter

Comment: Then try `abline(-1.0364513, 4.5729532)`

Comment: But you probably really want either `lm(weight ~ poly(diameter, 2, raw=TRUE))`  OR `lm(weight ~ poly(diameter, 3, raw=TRUE))`

Comment: or `lm(log(weight) ~ log(diameter))` ...